# Publish azure website with azure storage/SQL?

Tags: windows, azure

Is it possible to publish a website with azure storage and azure sql? I dont want a cloudapp.

I got connectionstring in my webconfig for my website, which also seems to hold my connectionstring for the sql database, but there is nothing for the azure storage(?)

How do i publish with azure storage when i dont have a webrole?

My website has linked resources with SQL and Storage.

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.  Do you want to publish a website to azure that doesn't integrate with an SQL Server and only integrates with Azure Table Storage?

Comment: I want to publish a mvc project as a website, not a cloudapp, that uses azure storage/sql.

This is my connectionstring in my webconfig:
<add name="UserAccountContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:jjay2mhwc6.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=rejtabilden_db;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: Ive added a key in appsettings aswell:

<add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=X;AccountKey==" />

Here is cloudstorageaccount 

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));

Comment: @user3276084 - please edit your question with any additional info; don't post as comments.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a cloud service to host a website on Azure.

You can use ([Azure Websites](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/web-sites/) to deploy your ASP.NET Website to - no requirement to use either SQL or Table Storage.

Comment: Hi!

Look at my two previous comments. Am I on the right path here? Anyway when i try to publish my website i get:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Have you added the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime reference to your solution?  If so, did you do it with NuGet?  Either ServiceRuntime is not in your solution, or one of its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Alright found the answer. It couldnt find the connectionstring i added for storage so i had to add system.configuration reference and change my code abit.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Thanks everyone